# Prolog - How to return a list of elements found in a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have a list of words and I am checking each word if exists in another list using the predicate `member(H,L)` (`H` being the head of the list containing the words that I need to check and `L` containing the list of words that I am checking with.

I am trying to extract only those words that are found in the `L` list. I have attempted to use the code below but the returning list consists of nested lists, apart from the fact that the first element is not initialized.

```
foundValues([],_,[]).   
foundValues([H|T],L,K) :-
    member(H,L),
    !,
    foundValues(T,L,[K|H]).
foundValues([_|T],L,K) :-
    foundValues(T,L,K).
```

The `K` variable should be holding the required output list.

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: With SWI-Prolog you can also use builtin predicate intersection/3.

Answer (score 0):

Second line should be:

```
foundValues([H|T],L,[H|K]) :- member(H,L), !, foundValues(T,L,K).
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, try to issue a `trace/0` call (or equivalent in your implementation) before you run your predicate. You'd have seen here that your recursion isn't quite right.

Here is how a proper recursion ([@user1126943](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126943/user1126943)) looks like when executed :

```
[trace]  ?- foundValues([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], R).
   Call: (6) foundValues([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], _G383) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:member(1, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) lists:member(1, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (7) foundValues([2], [1, 2, 3], _G465) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(2, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:member(2, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) foundValues([], [1, 2, 3], _G468) ? creep
   Exit: (8) foundValues([], [1, 2, 3], []) ? creep
   Exit: (7) foundValues([2], [1, 2, 3], [2]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) foundValues([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]) ? creep
R = [1, 2].
```

Basically the list is built backwards as you can see. First we reach the base case (`[]`) and then we add the elements depending on how we reached this case (meaning depending if element is a member of the second list or not here).